# Can I change limits of integration from $[-P/2,P/2]$ to $[0,P]$?

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

For a function $f(x+2\pi)=f(x)$, 
I have the usual FS coefficient $a_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t)\cos(nt)\, dt$ and equivalent for $b_n$.

Say I now have a function with period $P$, $g(x+P)=g(x)$ and use the change of variable $t=\frac{2\pi}{P}x$, 
$$
a_n=\frac{2}{P}\int_{-P/2}^{P/2}g(x)\cos\Big(\frac{2\pi n }{P}x\Big)\, dx
$$

Is it correct to change the limits from $[-P/2,P/2]$ to $[0,P]$, i.e.
\begin{align}
a_n&=\frac{2}{P}\int_{-P/2}^{P/2}g(x)\cos\Big(\frac{2\pi n }{P}x\Big)\, dx\\
&=\frac{2}{P}\int_{0}^{P}g(x)\cos\Big(\frac{2\pi n }{P}x\Big)\, dx \qquad ?
\end{align}

Comment: This question should be corrected. There's $t$ on the integral over $x$, and $f$ where I suppose $g$ should be.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a traditional proof.
Observe that

$$a_n =
\frac{2}{P}\int_{-P/2}^{0}g(x)\cos\Big(\frac{2\pi n }{P}x\Big)\, dx
+ \frac{2}{P}\int_{0}^{P/2}g(x)\cos\Big(\frac{2\pi n }{P}x\Big)\, dx$$

Now, consider

\begin{align}
\alpha_n&=\frac{2}{P}\int_{0}^{P}g(x)\cos\Big(\frac{2\pi n }{P}x\Big)\, dx\\
&=\frac{2}{P}\int_{0}^{P/2}g(x)\cos\Big(\frac{2\pi n }{P}x\Big)\, dx
+ \frac{2}{P}\int_{P/2}^{P}g(x)\cos\Big(\frac{2\pi n }{P}x\Big)\, dx
\end{align}

We have hence that $\alpha_n=a_n$ if and only if

$$
\int_{P/2}^{P}g(x)\cos\Big(\frac{2\pi n }{P}x\Big)\, dx
=
\int_{-P/2}^{0}g(x)\cos\Big(\frac{2\pi n }{P}x\Big)\, dx\tag{$*$}
$$

Now, consider the change of variables $u=x+P$.
Then $du=dx$, $u=P/2$ when $x=-P/2$ and $u=P$ when $x=0$.
Applying the substitution to the RHS on $(*)$ yields:

\begin{align}
\int_{-P/2}^{0}g(x)\cos\Big(\frac{2\pi n }{P}x\Big)\, dx
&= \int_{P/2}^{P}g(u-P)\cos\Big(\frac{2\pi n }{P}\,(u-P)\Big)\, dx\\
&= \int_{P/2}^{P}g(u)\cos\Big(\frac{2\pi n }{P}\,u - 2\pi n\Big)\, dx\\
&= \int_{P/2}^{P}g(u)\cos\Big(\frac{2\pi n }{P}\,u\Big)\, dx
\end{align}

which is precisely $(*)$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Since the function is periodic with period P, the graph of the function over the interval (-P/2,0) is identical to the graph over the interval (P/2,P).